# Parse string with regex and get desired output

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to parse this string

`[[delay-4]]Welcome! [[delay-2]]Do you have some questions for us?[[delay-1]] Please fill input field!`

I need to get something like this:

```
[
    [0] => '[[delay-4]]Welcome!',
    [1] => '[[delay-2]]Do you have some questions for us?',
    [2] => '[[delay-1]] Please fill input field!
];
```

String can also be something like this (without [[delay-4]] on beginning):

`Welcome! [[delay-2]]Do you have some questions for us?[[delay-1]] Please fill input field!`

Expected output should be something like this:

```
    [
        [0] => 'Welcome!',
        [1] => '[[delay-2]]Do you have some questions for us?',
        [2] => '[[delay-1]] Please fill input field!
    ];
```

I tried with this regex (https://regex101.com/r/Eqztl1/1/)

```
(?:\[\[delay-\d+]])?([\w \\,?!.@#$%^&*()|`\]~\-='\"{}]+)
```

But I have problem with that regex if someone writes just one `[` in text, regex fails and if I include `[` to match I got wrong results.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? You current patter will give you that output https://3v4l.org/MvSiH Do you want to match all consecutive square brackets even when they are unbalanced? Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/g5PlFl/1

Comment: you regex working fine for both string:- https://3v4l.org/PWDK9  and https://3v4l.org/MvSiH  so what problem you are facing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern

```
(?:[[delay-\d+]])?([\w \,?!.@#$%^&*()|`]~-='\"{}]+)
```

there is no opening `[` in the character class. The problem is that if you add it, you get as you say wrong results.

That is because after matching after matching delay, the character class in the next part which now contains the `[` can match the rest of the characters including those of the delay part.

What you could do is to add `[` and make the match non greedy in combination with a positive lookahead to assert either the next match for the delay part or the end of the string to also match the last instance.

If you are not using the capturing group and only want the result you can omit it.

```
(?:\[\[delay-\d+]])?[\w \\,?!.@#$%^&*()|`[\]~\-='\"{}]+?(?=\[\[delay-\d+]]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1eER8t/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/sUapK)

Answer (score 2):

Two simpler actions might be the route to get the result:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\s*(\[\[delay-\d+]])/i', "\n$1", $subject);
$result = preg_split('/\r?\n/i', $result, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Can be seen running here:
https://ideone.com/Z5tZI3
and here:
https://ideone.com/vnSNYI

This assumes that newline characters don't have special meaning and are OK to split on.

---

UPDATE: As noted in the comments below it's possible with a single split.

```
$result = preg_split('/(?=\[\[delay-\d+]])/i', $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

But there are possible issues with zero-length matches and regular expressions, you would have to do your own research on that.

Comment: What if the string contains line-breaks? It can be done with only one `preg_split` with your first pattern if you change your capture group with a lookahead. `]` isn't a special character.

Comment: Sure you can - but then you have to be aware of the issues around zero-length matches which is a complex issue to have to explain.

Comment: What kind of issues are you speaking about?

Comment: Zero-length matching issues, some of which are detailed here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html Note it's unclear how this is effects `preg_split`.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/j3IeT : By force of habit I have never see it as an issue! Whatever, since you use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag, it isn't a problem.

Comment: Problems with empty matches are more in Ecmascript with `RegExp.prototype.exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without regex too.

Explode on `[[` and loop the array. If the start of the item is "delay" then add `[[`

```
$str = '[[delay-4]]Welcome! [[delay-2]]Do you have some questions for us?[[delay-1]] Please fill input field!';

$arr = array_filter(explode("[[", $str));

foreach($arr as &$val){
    if(substr($val,0,5) == "delay") $val = "[[" . $val;
}

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/sIui1

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie Since OPs own regex is hardcoded "delay" then I think we can assume it's not an issue

Comment: I am agreed, but still you can add a more generic way too, apart from current answer. There is no harm in that i think :).  https://3v4l.org/7H1AR  And https://3v4l.org/npM0p

Comment: This will fail if text with pattern "[[some text]]" is present in text.
Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: @AleksaArsić always include the fringe cases in your question. How should we know it was even possible to have [[some text]]? It's easily fixed but I see no point in doing so because I'm quite sure there will be a new case coming around the corner.